# ClickOnce Installation as Administrator gives "A referral was returned from the server"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application. When user download the installer of this app and select run as Administrator, it gives an error pop-up saying "A referral was returned from the server"
How can I avoid this? Also, i was reading that a ClickOnce application can't do anything that require administrator privileges. If that is the case, do I need to switch to Windows Installer package if my application will need some file/printer access on the user's system?